# Prevent dock from auto-showing on mouse over

Tags: mac, snow-leopard, keyboard, dock

I currently have dock to auto-hide and would like it to stay hidden until I explicitly show it using a keyboard shortcut such as the "Move focus to dock" or "Turn Dock Hiding On/Off". I basically don't want it to inadvertently pop open when I move mouse to the edge of the screen (e.g., to access a scrollbar in a fullscreen app), and get in the way. I tried moving it to the left, which slightly reduced the inconvenience, but I am still ending up triggering it, as I use many apps in fullscreen mode, and tend to reach out to all sides. Since I am a heavy keyboard user, I don't mind occasionally using keyboard to select something in the dock (I map Ctrl+Esc to move focus to dock, and type the first one or two chars of the app to select it and press  to run it).

I have come across workarounds that work well to (effectively permanently) disable it, but not good for my use case. E.g., [this one to slow it down](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/34874/7347) and [this one to make it one pixel high](https://superuser.com/a/18257/26006) and http://www.chaoticsoftware.com/extras.html.

I looked through all the dock defaults by running command `defaults find .dock`, and nothing seemed relevant, but may be I missed something because it wasn't obvious, or may be because it has no entry (like a hidden default?). Anybody has any solutions or ideas?

Answer (score 4):

There's another hidden preference for the delay before the animation starts:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -float 9999999
osascript -e 'quit app "Dock"'
```

It doesn't affect full screen windows though.

This would increase the delay to about a second:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -float 0.5
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to make any difference, is this supposed to work on snow leopard?

Comment: I don't have an installation of 10.6 anymore, but it works for me on 10.8.

Comment: I wonder if it is specific to 10.8. Could you tell me how you came across this hidden setting, just to go back and look for more information?

Comment: I think I found it independently with [gdb](http://arcticmac.home.comcast.net/~arcticmac/tutorials/gdbFindingPrefs.html), but it's also been mentioned on a lot of websites like [Mac OS X Hints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20120326061614691) and [OS X Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/27/remove-auto-hide-dock-delay-mac-os-x/).

Comment: Thanks for the links. On Mac OS X Hints, couple of people mentioned that it didn't work in leopard and snow leopard, but one person said it worked in snow leopard, not sure what the difference is.