# How to remove dock hiding animation?

Tags: terminal, dock, animation

I'm aware of the command

[How can I make auto-hide/show for the dock faster?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33600/how-can-i-make-auto-hide-show-for-the-dock-faster)

however, I want to be able to use only the command "opt+cmd+d" to hide or show the dock. The reason for this is that I do a lot of editing on programs such as ableton, pro tools, and now will most likely move to davinci resolve, and it's really frustrating to me whenever my mouse needs to use the edge of the screen and the dock shows up. Would greatly appreciate it if someone knows how to actually hide the animation instead of making the dock appear in 0 seconds.

Thank you.

Comment: The linked question gives a variable you can use to set the delay much higher.

Comment: however it also affects it when I use the "opt+cmd+d" and it takes just as long to appear to be usable again.

Comment: Do you want to be able to show\hide the dock using keyboard shortcut but disable it for mouse? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/67142/prevent-dock-from-auto-showing-on-mouse-over